# How does OWASP ESAPI protect against direct object reference vulnerabilities?

Tags: appsec, attack-prevention, owasp, esapi

What other good solutions are there?

---

From the [Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8431/it-security/8446#8446)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summarizing atdre's link: OWASP ESAPI conveniently provides a mapping from a set of indirect references to the direct references, so convenient that you can even use a different mapping upon each request to your service.

Alternatives include container-managed security, Apache Shiro, and Spring Security, all of which are discussed in a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782720/when-to-move-from-container-managed-security-to-alternatives-like-apache-shiro).

Answer (score 3):

In the open-source OWASP ESAPI project, there is an example architecture with the correct controls in place to prevent IDORs. In that architecture is an Interface named AccessReferenceMap.

The **AccessReferenceMap** interface extends `java.io.Serializable` and is used to map a set of internal direct object references to a set of indirect references that are safe to disclose publicly. It can be used to help protect database keys, filenames, and other types of direct object references. As a rule, developers should not expose their direct object references, as this enables attackers to attempt to manipulate them.

https://static.javadoc.io/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.0.1/org/owasp/esapi/AccessReferenceMap.html